# how to create a zipped artifact of a maven javascript project

Tags: javascript, maven, plugins, zip

I have a Maven JavaScript NodeJS project. Following is the project structure

```
-- Project
  -- dist
  -- node_modules
  -- src
  -- target
  Gruntfile.js
  gulpfile.js
  package.json
  pom.xml
```

Is there a way to configure the pom so that it builds a zipped file of the `dist` folder and saves it in the output target directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible using the [`maven-assembly-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/). This is a very general plugin that can used to create a custom assembly of a project.

It is configured through an [`assembly.xml`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html) file. For your case, the configuration would be:

```xml
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
  <id>dist</id>
  <formats>
    <format>zip</format> <!-- create a zip archive -->
  </formats>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>dist</directory> <!-- source is the "dist" folder -->
      <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory> <!-- target is the root of the archive -->
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

The typical location for this file would be `src/main/assembly/assembly.xml`. Then, the POM would contain:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>assembly-dist</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

After invoking `mvn clean package`, the `target` folder will contain the zip file produced by this plugin.